# mod_rewrite RewriteRule is not working

Tags: mod-rewrite

This is a follow-up of this question: [Rewrite URL - how to get the hostname and the path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875405/rewrite-url-how-to-get-the-hostname-and-the-path)
And a copy of this: [mod_rewrite RewriteRule is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880996/mod-rewrite-rewriterule-is-not-working)

I got this Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(http://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)/([-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)\?([A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)$ http://www.xmldomain.com/bla/$2?$3&rtype=xslt&xsl=$1/$2.xsl
```

it seems to be correct, and exactly what I need. But it doesn't work on my server. I get a 404 page not found error.

mod_rewrite is enabled, as the following simple rule is working fine:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: Is the double http:// at the end (`http://http://www.xmldomain.com/bla/$2?$3&rtype=xslt&xsl=$1/$2.xsl`) intentional?

Comment: no. it wasn't intentional. i removed one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875405/rewrite-url-how-to-get-the-hostname-and-the-path/2876776#2876776 seems like a correct response to me. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, by default

> The Pattern will initially be matched
>   against the part of the URL after the
>   hostname and port, and before the
>   query string. If you wish to match
>   against the hostname, port, or query
>   string, use a RewriteCond with the
>   %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or
>   %{QUERY_STRING} variables
>   respectively.

So you cannot extract the hostname nor the query string this way. The simples way is to use the `%{HTTP_HOST}` and `%{QUERY_STRING}` server variables in the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.xmldomain.com/bla/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}&rtype=xslt&xsl=%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.xsl
```

EDIT

If you want to test the full URL, then you can use `RewriteCond` like this (note the `%` sign instead of the `$` sign in the rewrite rule):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} ...pattern...
RewriteRule . http://www.xmldomain.com/bla/%2?%3&rtype=xslt&xsl=%1/%2.xsl
```